# Weird top link bar after upgrading WSS2 to WSS3

Tags: wss-3.0, upgrade

Installed WSS2 on server 2003, not customized or changed, upgraded to WSS3 and the top link bar (home, documentation etc..) is vertical and appears to be broken. This looked the same before I changed the logo or added additional options (documentation, subversion) to the top link bar.

I'm pretty sure that menu is supposed to be horizontal

[image]

**Edit: I can confirm that this is only a problem in Chrome. Therefore I guess the site would require modification to resolve the cross browser problem**

This is what is causing the problem in chrome I think:

```
<tr>
            <td nowrap="" valign="middle"></td>
            <td class="ms-banner" width="99%" nowrap="" id="HBN100">

    <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderTopNavBar_PlaceHolderHorizontalNav_TopNavigationMenu" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_5">
    <img src="/WebResource.axd?d=53EgVo7MhZjaT5GI4NUrLCYtaeKOvhx6npAcsJcVXdS4rsOlmELCVLkVoDRoOE1PmP2U3AYZczLcBTCtwhrDqwxLjjA1&amp;t=634447411006093750" alt="" style="height:1px;width:0px;border-width:0px;"><span class="ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_4 ms-topnavselected zz1_TopNavigationMenu_10"><a accesskey="1" class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_3 ms-topnavselected zz1_TopNavigationMenu_9" href="/default.aspx" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Home</a></span> <img src="/WebResource.axd?d=53EgVo7MhZjaT5GI4NUrLCYtaeKOvhx6npAcsJcVXdS4rsOlmELCVLkVoDRoOE1PmP2U3AYZczLcBTCtwhrDqwxLjjA1&amp;t=634447411006093750" alt="" style="height:1px;width:0px;border-width:0px;"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=53EgVo7MhZjaT5GI4NUrLCYtaeKOvhx6npAcsJcVXdS4rsOlmELCVLkVoDRoOE1PmP2U3AYZczLcBTCtwhrDqwxLjjA1&amp;t=634447411006093750" alt="" style="height:1px;width:0px;border-width:0px;"><span class="ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_4"><a class="zz1_TopNavigationMenu_1 ms-topnav zz1_TopNavigationMenu_3" href="/General%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Documentation</a></span> <img src="/WebResource.axd?d=53EgVo7MhZjaT5GI4NUrLCYtaeKOvhx6npAcsJcVXdS4rsOlmELCVLkVoDRoOE1PmP2U3AYZczLcBTCtwhrDqwxLjjA1&amp;t=634447411006093750" alt="" style="height:1px;width:0px;border-width:0px;">
</div>




            </td>
            <td class="ms-banner">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            <td valign="bottom" align="right" style="position:relative;bottom:0;left:0;">
             <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tbody><tr>
               <td>
                <table height="100%" class="ms-siteaction" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                 <tbody><tr>
                       <td class="ms-siteactionsmenu" id="siteactiontd">


                        <span style="display:none"><menu type="ServerMenu" id="zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain" largeiconmode="true"><ie:menuitem id="zz10_MenuItem_Create" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/Actionscreate.gif" onmenuclick="window.location = '/_layouts/create.aspx';" text="Create" description="Add a new library, list, or web page to this website." menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="ctl00_PlaceHolderTopNavBar_SiteActionsMenuMain_ctl00_MenuItem_EditPage" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/ActionsEditPage.gif" onmenuclick="window.location = 'javascript:MSOLayout_ChangeLayoutMode(false);';" text="Edit Page" description="Add, remove, or update Web Parts on this page." menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem><ie:menuitem id="zz11_MenuItem_Settings" type="option" iconsrc="/_layouts/images/ActionsSettings.gif" onmenuclick="window.location = '/_layouts/settings.aspx';" text="Site Settings" description="Manage site settings on this site." menugroupid="100"></ie:menuitem></menu></span><div><div><span title="Open Menu"><div id="zz12_SiteActionsMenu_t" class="" onmouseover="MMU_PopMenuIfShowing(this);MMU_EcbTableMouseOverOut(this, true)" hoveractive="ms-siteactionsmenuhover" hoverinactive="" onclick=" MMU_Open(byid('zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz12_SiteActionsMenu'),event,false, null, 0);" foa="MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz12_SiteActionsMenu')" oncontextmenu="this.click(); return false;" nowrap="nowrap"><a id="zz12_SiteActionsMenu" accesskey="/" href="#" onclick="javascript:return false;" style="cursor:pointer;white-space:nowrap;" onfocus="MMU_EcbLinkOnFocusBlur(byid('zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain'), this, true);" onkeydown="MMU_EcbLinkOnKeyDown(byid('zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain'), MMU_GetMenuFromClientId('zz12_SiteActionsMenu'), event);" oncontextmenu="this.click(); return false;" menutokenvalues="MENUCLIENTID=zz12_SiteActionsMenu,TEMPLATECLIENTID=zz9_SiteActionsMenuMain" serverclientid="zz12_SiteActionsMenu">Site Actions<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" border="0" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)."></a><img align="absbottom" src="/_layouts/images/whitearrow.gif" alt=""></div></span></div></div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                </tbody></table>
               </td>
              </tr>
             </tbody></table>
            </td>
           </tr>
```

I am having to use Chrome because of this problem in internet explorer if anyone can help with that also? :'( Sometimes, I really hate microsoft.
[Context menu: Actions don't work with IE 8](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15314/wss-3-hover-over-item-click-the-arrow-drop-down-menu-appears-but-actions-only)

Comment: you blanked the url in the adress bar, but not in the page content itself.....

Comment: it's OK I realised, and then realised its an internal IP address anyway. Thanks for point that out though ;-D

Comment: Chrome isn't a tier 1 or 2 browser for WSS 3.0.  IE is preferred with Firefox being the best alternative. Chrome, Safari, and Opera do not work well at all.

Comment: Can you tell me why the drop down menus work in chrome/ff but dont work in ie7/ie8/compat - totally fresh install...